# Impresión de datos desde la DB con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Realizo la impresión del siguiente dato mediante PHP, pero al agregar a href al inicio, para volver ese dato un link que me dirija a la dirección web mostrada, no funciona.

```
             <a href=" <?php echo $datos['url']; ?> "> </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas agregar un texto a la etiqueta para que sea visible, por ejemplo

```
<a href="<?php echo $datos['url'] ?>" >TEXTO AQUÍ</a>
```

Comment: Funcionó, TEXTO AQUÍ se convierte en el link que me redirige, gracias.

Comment: El ancla siempre existió, solo que no tenia dimensiones para mostrarse en pantalla. Se le dan dimensiones agregándole algún texto o por medio de CSS.